# JFileChooser embedded in a JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jfilechooser, fileopendialog

I am writing a java program that needs a file open dialog.  The file open dialog isn't difficult, I'm hoping to use a `JFileChooser`.  My problem is that I would like to have a dual pane `JFrame` (consisting of 2 `JPanels`).  The left panel would have a `JList`, and the right panel would have a file open dialog.

When I use `JFileChooser.showOpenDialog()` this opens the dialog box above all other windows, which isn't what I want.  Is there any way to have the `JFileChooser` (or maybe another file selection dialog) display inside a `JPanel` and not pop-up above it?

Here is the code that I've tried, at this point it's very simplified. I'm only trying to get the `JFileChooser` to be embedded in the `JPanel` at this point.

```
public class JFC extends JFrame{
    public JFC()
    {
        setSize(800,600);

        JPanel panel= new JPanel();

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        panel.add(chooser);

        setVisible(true);

        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFC blah = new JFC();
    }
}
```

I have also tried calling `chooser.showOpenDialog` with `this` and `panel`, but to no avail. Also, I have tried adding the `JFileChooser` directly to the frame. Both of the attempts listed above still have the `JFileChooser` pop up in front of the frame or panel (depending on which I add the `JFileChooser` to).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JFileChooser extends JComponent and Component so you should be able to add it directly to your frame.

```
JFileChooser fc = ...
JPanel panel ...
panel.add(fc);
```

Answer (score 5):

To access the "buttons" in the file chooser, you will have to add an ActionListener to it:

```
fileChooser.addActionListener(this);
[...]

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action)
{
    if (action.getActionCommand().equals("CancelSelection"))
    {
        System.out.printf("CancelSelection\n");
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
    }
    if (action.getActionCommand().equals("ApproveSelection"))
    {
        System.out.printf("ApproveSelection\n");
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are adding the JFileChooser on the fly, you will need to call revalidate().

Steve's answer is correct. You can add a JFileChooser to other containers.

Answer (score 2):

To Johannes: thanks for your useful snippet.

Instead of "ApproveSelection" and "CancelSelection" I used the defined constants `JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION` and `JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION`