# how can i make a program take any path itself without making browse

Tags: java, algorithm, netbeans

Is there any java code or an algorithm can use it to make an application (wrote in netbeans) take any path itself for any text or folder etc... , without making browse or fileChooser? ( for example : like winrar , it can take the path itself to make compress for the text that click on ).

Comment: yes, what have you tried? Are you talking about the command line or in a GUI program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFileChooser embedded in a JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259575/jfilechooser-embedded-in-a-jpanel)

Comment: GUI program , i make a compress and extract program , and i add it to context menu , so i need when i click on it , to take a oath itself and making compress without make browse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you mean is the "right-click integration" of WinRAR:

[image: Winrar right-click integration]

If so, you can do that with any program. How this is implemented depends on your operating system:

- [For Windows, Add a Registry Key](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/)
- [For Mac OSX, Add it in the system-settings](http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-customise-the-right-click-menu-in-mac-os-x/)
- For Linux, there is no "one fits all" solution, as it depends on the file-browser you're using (Nautilus, Thunar, etz). Have a look at their documentation.

These are just some results that came up by searching for `[operating-system] right click integration`. Go see for yourself.

Comment: yes , that is what i mean , i add it in the "right-click integration" , but the problem that i want to make it take the path for the text for example , without i make browse when i click on compress

Comment: You'll get the path to the file the user clicked on as a parameter in your `main(String[] args)`-method. Check the `args`-array.